# One producer, two consumers acting on one 'queue' produced by producer

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, producer-consumer

Preface: I'm new to multithreaded programming, and a little rusty with C++. My requirements are to use one mutex, and two conditions `mNotEmpty` and `mEmpty`. I must also create and populate the vectors in the way mentioned below.

I have one producer thread creating a vector of random numbers of size `n*2`, and two consumers inserting those values into two separate vectors of size `n`.

I am doing the following in the producer:

1. Lock the mutex: `pthread_mutex_lock(&mMutex1)`
2. Wait for consumer to say vector is empty: `pthread_cond_wait(&mEmpty,&mMutex1)`
3. Push back a value into the vector
4. Signal the consumer that the vector isn't empty anymore: `pthread_cond_signal(&mNotEmpty)`
5. Unlock the mutex: `pthread_mutex_unlock(&mMutex1)`
6. Return to step 1

In the consumer:

1. Lock the mutex: `pthread_mutex_lock(&mMutex1)`
2. Check to see if the vector is empty, and if so signal the producer: `pthread_cond_signal(&mEmpty)`
3. Else insert value into one of two new vectors (depending on which thread) and remove from original vector
4. Unlock the mutex: `pthread_mutex_unlock(&mMutex1)`
5. Return to step 1

What's wrong with my process? I keep getting segmentation faults or infinite loops.

Edit: Here's the code:

```
void Producer()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < mTotalNumberOfValues; i++){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mMutex1);

        pthread_cond_wait(&mEmpty,&mMutex1);
        mGeneratedNumber.push_back((rand() % 100) + 1);

        pthread_cond_signal(&mNotEmpty);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mMutex1);
    }
}

void Consumer(const unsigned int index)
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < mNumberOfValuesPerVector; i++){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mMutex1);
        if(mGeneratedNumber.empty()){
            pthread_cond_signal(&mEmpty);
        }else{
            mThreadVector.at(index).push_back[mGeneratedNumber.at(0)];
            mGeneratedNumber.pop_back();
        }

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mMutex1);
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be a lot easier to answer if you just presented a minimal compilable program which demonstrated your problem.

Comment: Well, if you wait inside a lock, then expect a deadlock somewhere at some point in the future.

Comment: Step 4 of the producer says to signal the consumer with mNotEmpty, but mNotEmpty isn't used by the consumer.

Comment: There are different issues with your code, including threading but also plain logic errors (for example, you pull the head of the generated number queue, but remove from the back). Try to first write a non-multithreaded produce and consume and test that in a single threaded program to see that it does what it promises. Once that is working, move to multithreading, and remember that produce and consume are symetric operations.

Comment: What is `mThreadVector[index].push_back[mGeneratedNumber.at(0)]` meant to be? This code does not compile. See http://sscce.org/

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I actually hadn't even written the part that you mentioned, but threw something together for this post. The idea is that there's only ever 1 (or 0) value(s) in mGeneratedNumber at any instant in time, so it doesn't really matter if I pull/remove from the front or back. I will try what you suggest, but I really think my misconceptions are with multithreading.

Comment: @Mankarse It really should be `mThreadVector.at(index).push_back(...`, I wasn't really paying too close attention to syntax since I just threw that piece together for this post. My vector operations aren't intended to be relevant to this post.

Comment: @wanovak: Well the seg-faults and infinite loops _could_ be a result of problematic vector operations. We would need the full, correct, code to tell. As it is, you are popping from the back of `mGeneratedValues`, but using the element from the front of `mGeneratedNumber`, and never removing elements from `mGeneratedNumber`.

Comment: @user1240436 If you wait without holding the lock, expect a race condition.  Holding the lock is a precondition for `pthread_cond_wait`.

Comment: @Mankarse My guess is that he meant for `mGeneratedValues` and `mGeneratedNumber` to be the same; that the difference is a typo.  (Otherwise: no one ever puts anything into `mGeneratedNumber`, and he accesses it without ever checking whether there's anything there.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the rationale behind the way you're doing
things.  In the usual consumer-provider idiom, the provider pushes as
many items as possible into the channel, waiting only if there is
insufficient space in the channel; it doesn't wait for empty.  So the 
usual idiom would be:

provider (to push one item):

```
pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex );
while ( ! spaceAvailable() ) {
    pthread_cond_wait( &spaceAvailableCondition, &mutex );
}
pushTheItem();
pthread_cond_signal( &itemAvailableCondition );
pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex );
```

and on the consumer side, to get an item:

```
pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex );
while ( ! itemAvailable() ) {
    pthread_cond_wait( &itemAvailableCondition, &mutex );
}
getTheItem();
pthread_cond_signal( &spaceAvailableCondition );
pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex );
```

Note that for each condition, one side signals, and the other waits.  (I
don't see any wait in your consumer.)  And if there is more than one
process on either side, I'd recommend using `pthread_cond_broadcast`,
rather than `pthread_cond_signal`.

There are a number of other issues in your code.  Some of them look more
like typos: you should copy/paste actual code to avoid this.  Do you
really mean to read and pop `mGeneratedValues`, when you push into
`mGeneratedNumber`, and check whether that is empty?  (If you actually
do have two different queues, then you're popping from a queue where no
one has pushed.)  And you don't have any loops waiting for the
conditions; you keep iterating through the number of elements you
expect (incrementing the counter each time, so you're likely to
gerninate long before you should)—I can't see an infinite loop,
but I can readily see a endless wait in `pthread_cond_wait` in the
producer.  I don't see a core dump off hand, but what happens when one
of the processes terminates (probably the consumer, because it never
waits for anything); if it ends up destroying the mutex or the condition
variables, you could get a core dump when another process attempts to
use them.

Answer (score 1):

In producer, call `pthread_cond_wait` only when queue is not empty. Otherwise you get blocked forever due to a race condition.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider taking mutex only after condition is fulfilled, e.g.

```
producer()
{
    while true
    {
        waitForEmpty();
        takeMutex();
        produce();
        releaseMutex();
    }
}

consumer()
{
    while true
    {
        waitForNotEmpty();
        takeMutex();
        consume();
        releaseMutex();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I thought at first too, but I looked up pthread_cond_wait, and it expects to be passed a locked mutex, which it unlocks before it starts waiting.

Comment: -1 because this is simply wrong.  You can't `waitForEmpty` without holding a mutex, and you can't release the mutex between `waitForEmpty` and `produce` without risking a race condition.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. After thinking about it I figured that doing it as I wrote might cause a race condition, if, say, two consumers finished waiting, only one takes the mutex and empties the vector, and the other enters the protected section.

Anyway, here is a nice working example of what you are trying to do:

http://www.cs.loyola.edu/~jglenn/702/S2008/Examples/ProducerConsumer/pc_cpp.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is a solution to a similar problem like you. In this program producer produces a no and writes it to a array(buffer) and a maintains a file then update a status(status array) about it, while on getting data in the array(buffer) consumers start to consume(read and write to their file) and update a status that it has consumed. when producer looks that both the consumer has consumed the data it overrides the data with a new value and goes on. for convenience here i have restricted the code to run for 2000 nos.

// Producer-consumer //

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <pthread.h>

#define MAX 100

using namespace std;

int dataCount = 2000;

int buffer_g[100];
int status_g[100];

void *producerFun(void *);
void *consumerFun1(void *);
void *consumerFun2(void *);

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

pthread_cond_t dataNotProduced = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t dataNotConsumed = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

int main()
{

  for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    status_g[i] = 0;

  pthread_t producerThread, consumerThread1, consumerThread2;

  int retProducer = pthread_create(&producerThread, NULL, producerFun, NULL);
  int retConsumer1 = pthread_create(&consumerThread1, NULL, consumerFun1, NULL);
  int retConsumer2 = pthread_create(&consumerThread2, NULL, consumerFun2, NULL);

  pthread_join(producerThread, NULL);
  pthread_join(consumerThread1, NULL);
  pthread_join(consumerThread2, NULL);

  return 0;

}

void *producerFun(void *)
{
    //file to write produced data by producer
    const char *producerFileName = "producer.txt";
    ofstream producerFile(producerFileName);
    int index = 0, producerCount = 0;

    while(1)
    {
      pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

      if(index == MAX)
      {
        index = 0;
      }
      if(status_g[index] == 0)
      {

        static int data = 0;
        data++;

        cout << "Produced:  " << data << endl;

        buffer_g[index] = data;

        producerFile << data << endl;

        status_g[index] = 5;

        index ++;
        producerCount ++;

        pthread_cond_broadcast(&dataNotProduced);
      }
      else
      {
        cout << ">> Producer is in wait.." << endl;
        pthread_cond_wait(&dataNotConsumed, &mutex);
      }
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

      if(producerCount == dataCount)
      {
        producerFile.close();
        return NULL;
      }
    }
}

void *consumerFun1(void *)
{
  const char *consumerFileName = "consumer1.txt";
  ofstream consumerFile(consumerFileName);
  int index = 0, consumerCount = 0;

  while(1)
  {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    if(index == MAX)
    {
      index = 0;
    }

    if(status_g[index] != 0 && status_g[index] != 2)
    {
      int data = buffer_g[index];

      cout << "Cosumer1 consumed: " << data << endl;
      consumerFile << data << endl;

      status_g[index] -= 3;

      index ++;
      consumerCount ++;

      pthread_cond_signal(&dataNotConsumed);
    }
    else
    {
      cout << "Consumer1 is in wait.." << endl;
      pthread_cond_wait(&dataNotProduced, &mutex);
    }
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    if(consumerCount == dataCount)
    {
      consumerFile.close();
      return NULL;
    }
  }
}

void *consumerFun2(void *)
{
  const char *consumerFileName = "consumer2.txt";
  ofstream consumerFile(consumerFileName);
  int index = 0, consumerCount = 0;

  while(1)
  {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    if(index == MAX)
    {
      index = 0;
    }

    if(status_g[index] != 0 && status_g[index] != 3)
    {


      int data = buffer_g[index];
      cout << "Consumer2 consumed: " << data << endl;
      consumerFile << data << endl;

      status_g[index] -= 2;

      index ++;
      consumerCount ++;

      pthread_cond_signal(&dataNotConsumed);
    }
    else
    {
      cout << ">> Consumer2 is in wait.." << endl;
      pthread_cond_wait(&dataNotProduced, &mutex);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    if(consumerCount == dataCount)
    {
      consumerFile.close();
      return NULL;
    }
  }
} 

Here is only one problem that producer in not independent to produce, that is it needs to take lock on the whole array(buffer) before it produces new data, and if the mutex is locked by consumer it waits for that and vice versa, i am trying to look for it.
```